# Troubles with Advertising Studio Facebook

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, facebook, advertising-studio

In Advertising Studio I'm building a audience in facebook to test the functionality and I'm receiving the error message bellow. I've search for some miss configuration that i've done, but I cant reach the answer

[image]

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this before I'll contact Salesforce support?

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be self explanatory. Do you own the facebook page that you are trying to integrate with AB

Comment: Yes, I do. I don't know if there's something else to configurate in facebook, but I am the owner

Answer (score 0):

Posting useful Salesforce Ad Studio help article to resolve this error!
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384638&type=1